# Group action on $2$x$2$?

Tags: operators, group-theory, representation-theory

Group action of group $C_{3v}$ is defined for all $2$x$2$ matrices over field of complex numbers, for all $g$ from $C_{3v}$ 
$$D(g)A=E(g)AE(g^{-1})$$

where $E$ is $2D$ representation of $C_{3v}$. How with group projectors find invariant matrices for defined action. How decompose representtation $D(g)$ in irreducible components of group $C_{3v}$?

My idea is that matrix $A$ can decompose in Kronecker product of two vectors from space of $2D$ vectors. Thee first vector(column vector) $\mathbf{v}$ is from vector space $V$, and the second is from adjoint space $V^\dagger$
$\mathbf{w}$. So $A=\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}$. then

$$D(g)A=(E(g)\mathbf{v})\otimes(E(g)\mathbf{w})^\dagger=[(E(g)\otimes(E(g))^\dagger][\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{\mathbf{w}^\dagger}]$$. But this is end :(

Comment: I would use a character table and just try to read off the direct sum decomposition using the traces of the irreps

Comment: how we find dirrect sum decomposition ? But I think that my idea wa wrong ?

Comment: Suppose $D = \oplus_{i=1}^n a_i D^{(i)}$ for irreps $D^{(i)}$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$ is a finite-dimensional representation. Then $\chi_D = \mathrm{tr}(D) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{tr}(a_i D^{(i)}) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_i$ where $\chi_i$ is the character of the irrep and $\chi_D$ the character of the representation $D$. In order words it is useful to know $D$ and from the character table you can find $a_i$'s. You can also use that characters are orthonormal w.r.t. the inner product

Comment: My quesstion now is: Is representation $D(g)$ regular ?

Comment: Let $e \in C_{3v}$ be the identity element and $g \in C_{3v}$ with $g \neq e$. Then you should check whether $\chi_D(e) = |C_{3v}|$ (number of elements in $C_{3v}$) and $\chi_D(g) = 0$ for all $g \in G: g \neq e$. Then $D$ is regular.

Comment: If $ A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ is $χ_{D}(e)=a+b$ ?

Comment: this problem is a part of problem, where I must find invariant matrices in irreducible space $E$ for all $g∈C_{3v}$